# Write data into new row in excel file each time function is called

Tags: java, excel

I am trying to write data into new row each time the function is called in selenium webdriver

I have written the function as below

```
public class ExcelFunctions 
{  


    XSSFSheet sh;

    int i=0;     

public boolean entertestcaseinexcel(String tcnumber, String description, String value) throws IOException
{
    boolean status = true;  

    try
    {

        XSSFRow row = sh.createRow(i);

        row.createCell(0).setCellValue(tcnumber);
        row.createCell(1).setCellValue(description);
        row.createCell(2).setCellValue(value);
        i++;
    }

    catch(Exception e)
    {
        status = false;
    }
    return status;
}

}
```

I am calling the above function here

```
import Selenium.ExcelFunctions;

public class ExcelWrite {



    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {


        ExcelFunctions EF = new ExcelFunctions();

          File file = new File("D:\\Selenium_Training\\SeleniumNewFile.xlsx");
          FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);

          XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);

          XSSFSheet  sh = wb.getSheetAt(0); 

          EF.entertestcaseinexcel("TC001", "Successfully Logged in", "Pass");

          FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(file);

          wb.write(fout);    

          fout.close();


    }

}
```

The problem is i am able to run the script but i am not getting any value written to the excel.

Could you please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: if you find the answer I provided useful then please accept it as answer, If my answer does not answer your question then let me know what exactly are you looking for.

Comment: I don't see where you are saving the file after making the changes. Make sure you save it to store the changes.

Answer (score 1):

You have hard coded the cell number value in entertestcaseinexcel function. Take that value from the caller of your method. below is sample code you can use -

```
public static void writeTestResultToXLSX(File scenarioFile, String testCaseID, int cellNo, resultEnum rEnum) {
FileInputStream fis;
try {
fis = new FileInputStream(scenarioFile);

XSSFWorkbook workbook = (XSSFWorkbook) WorkbookFactory.create(fis);
XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
int rowNum = Integer.parseInt(testCaseID);
Row row = sheet.getRow(rowNum);
row.createCell(cellNo).setCellValue(rEnum.toString());
fis.close();
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(scenarioFile);
workbook.write(fos);
fos.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (EncryptedDocumentException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (InvalidFormatException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

In above code, scenarioFile is the name of the excel file you want to read, cellNo is the cellNo where you want to write the result back, rEnum is Enum that has predefined value - PASS and FAIL. 
In below way, you can call this function -

```
ApachePOIMethods.writeTestResultToXLSX(scenarioFile, testCaseID, XLSXresultCell, resultEnum.FAIL);
```

One thing to make sure is not to hard code anything, the complete code is big so cannot be copy-pasted here so as to keep answer short, you can find complete script [here.](http://selenium-coding.blogspot.in/2016/05/generalized-apache-poi-script-for.html)